# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS server - network configuration problem during setup

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, netplan

When installing from current server iso's in a VMWare VM and without a DHCP Server present, both Ubuntu installers are not able to manualy configure a ethernet interface.

With the ubuntu-18.04.2-server-amd64.iso the manual network configuration dialog stops after entering the hostname. and you end up with an `unconfigured 01-netcfg.yaml`

With the `ubuntu-18.04.02-live-server-amd64.iso`, the setup simply restarts after trying to save the manual IP configuration.

Did canonical forget to implement the netplan part of the setup?
;-)

Comment: Same behavior for us.

Comment: Above my pay grade but found these links: https://blogging.dragon.org.uk/test-networking-lab-ubuntu-on-18-04/ and https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1768827

Comment: I remember I had the same problem. It was quite tricky to configure the yaml-file manually. After that I configured a DHCP Server to avoid this problem.